# How to add home property of Home.dart to main.dart correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to add `home.dart` and `splashscreen.dart` to main dart but I don't know how to do that correctly.

I did it using the following method.In that method `splashscreen.dart` works perfectly.

Main.dart

```
void main() =>runApp(MaterialApp(


    initialRoute:'/',
    routes:{
      '/': (context) => Splash(),
      '/home':(context) => 
     Home(storage:Storage()),
    },
    ));
```

But when I run the home.dart as a single file without main.dart and splashscreen.dart it works perfectly.

Using of void main when running home.dart only.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
home:Home(storage:Storage()),

));
```

How can I combine `home.dart` and splashscreen.dart in `main.dart` correctly?

Comment: Dont use main () in your home.dart. Just start as the home stateful or stateless widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the code below w yours, it works perfectly:

```
void main() =>runApp(MaterialApp(


  initialRoute:'/',
  routes:{
    '/': (context) => Splash(),
    '/home':(context) => Home(),
  },
));

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: What about the storage class,How can I add to that code? I mean this " home:Home(storage:Storage())"

Comment: Where are you getting the home:Home(storage: Storage())  from @Axen_Rangs

Comment: BTW I didn't try your code..I'll try that and respond you

Comment: I'm getting it from Class which is created to read file in the disk

Comment: Can you post your ```Home``` widget ? @Axen_Rangs

Comment: I add the Storage class part that occurring the error...Can you please check it out

Comment: I need to see your ```Home Widget```. Why are you passing the ```Storage``` class to it @Axen_Rangs

Comment: Thanks I'm newbie to flutter...that's wrong I think..I have to correct the code without passing that values.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need to pass the value. @Axen_Rangs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213529/discussion-between-axen-rangs-and-t-t-sage).